# Get value of editable td in table with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a dynamic table :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td contenteditable='true'>Value1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td contenteditable='true'>Value2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get the value of the editable cell when the user finish writing `(blur)`

```
$('table td').focus(function () {
    console.log("focus ");
    console.log("echo each input "); // show every carac inputed

});
$('table td').blur(function () {
    console.log("blur ");
    console.log("echo the new value"); // show the new value

});
```

So my question how I can get the new value in `blur` event and how I get exactly which `td` is modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`input`** instead of **`focus`** if you want to show every character inputed.

You could use `$(this).text()` or `$(this).html()` to get the value in the td.

Hope this helps.

---

### snippet

```js
$('table td').on('input', function () {
  console.log($(this).text());
});

$('table td').on('blur', function () {
  console.log("blur new value : "+$(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td contenteditable='true'>Value1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td contenteditable='true'>Value2</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But this doesn't show any show any typed character.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question how i can get the new value in blur event

Using the [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html) method. (Or [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text), if you don't want the markup.) It's not the *value*, it's the new content. (`td` elements don't have a *value*.)

> and how i get exactly which td is modified

It's `this` in the `blur` event callback.

So:

```
$('table td').blur(function () {
    var newContent = $(this).html();
    // ...
});
```

---

Side note: Since `td` elements are invalid outside of tables, `$('table td')` is just the same as `$('td')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `text()` function like following.

```
$('table td').blur(function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table td').focusout(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

The focusout event occurs when an element (or any elements inside it) loses focus.
The focusout() method attaches a function to run when a focusout event occurs on the element, or any elements inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the *content* of `td` (it has no *value*!) with jQuery [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function, *e.g.*: `$(this).text()` or `$(this).html()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('table td').focus(function() {
    console.log("focus ");
    console.log("echo each input "); // show every carac inputed

  });
  $('table td').blur(function() {
    console.log("blur ");
    console.log("echo the new value: " + $(this).text()); // show the new value

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td contenteditable='true'>Value1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td contenteditable='true'>Value2</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$(this).text();`

```
$('table td').blur(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **keyup** instead of **focus** to get each letter, and **keypress** instead of **keyup** if you want to get the right letter case.

Check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/fgsusvst/)**.

```js
$(function(){
$('table td').keypress(function(e){
    var singleChar=String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
    console.log("focus ");
    console.log(singleChar); // show every carac inputed
});

$('table td').blur(function(){
    console.log("blur ");
    console.log($(this).text()); // show the new value
});
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td contenteditable='true'>Value1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td contenteditable='true'>Value2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```